# Why some guitarists add a plastic gizmo in the guitar's sound hole?

Tags: acoustic-guitar

I've seen so many people add something made of plastic in the sound hole of a guitar, but I don't know what it's called. So what is this and why do they use it?

Comment: Shouldn't it be "a piece of plastic" or "a plastic thing" or something similar. "A plastic" doesn't sound right to me and leaves me hanging

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can think of two different things.

First, a "sound-hole pickup", a device that allows you to mount magnetic pickups onto/into a guitar so that it can be amplified without using a microphone.

[image]

Second, feedback suppressor -- a device that dampens the resonance of the guitar so that it does not feed back when being played at high volumes.  Sometimes these are just called "soundhole plug" or "soundhole damper" or "guitar damper" etc.

[image]

Comment: I think you covered all the possibilities.  Like the pictures.  Plus 1!